# Im confuse with axios in seperate service file

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

Im now is learn vue.js, and i want to consume API from my backend (using spring).

This is **my service.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

class LowonganKerjaService {
    retrieveAllLoker() {
        return axios.get('http://localhost:8081/api/listLoker');
    }

    deleteLoker(idLowongan){
        return axios.delete('http://localhost:8081/api/${idLowongan}');
    }
}

export default new LowonganKerjaService();
```

this is my component

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>All Courses</h3>
    <div v-if="message" class="alert alert-success">
      {{message}}
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="loker in loker" v-bind:key="loker.idLowongan">
            <td>{{loker.idLowongan}}</td>
            <td>{{loker.deskripsi}}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning" v-on:click="deleteLokerClicked(loker.idLowongan)">
                Hapus
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LowonganKerjaService from '../../service/LowonganKerjaService';
export default {
    name : "LokerList",
    data() {
        return{
            loker : []
        };
    },

    methods:{
        refreshLoker(){
            LowonganKerjaService.retrieveAllLoker()
            .then(response => {
                this.loker = response.data;
            });
        },
        deleteLokerClicked(idLowongan){
          LowonganKerjaService.deleteLoker(idLowongan).then(()=> {
            this.message = 'Loker dengan ${idLowongan} berhasil dihapus';
            this.refreshLoker();
          });
        }

    },
    created(){
        this.refreshLoker();
    }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

and i got this error

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/service/LowonganKerjaService.js Module Error (from
>   ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>
> D:\Kuliah\TERM
>   6\Propensi\Implementasi\frontend-sixacti\src\service\LowonganKerjaService.js
>   10:17  error  'idLowongan' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

Oh and i've got error too when i use ${} in those service.
Why that error state that my 'idLowongan' is never used? is it because i wrong my syntaks or what?

Please somebody help me to give the reason

Thanks

**sorry for my bad language

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your code it looks like you're using a single quote (') and not a backtick (`) when you're attempting to use JS template literal. You can see an example of that [in the MSDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Since it is a string in your example and not a template literal the variable in the function's argument is never used.

Try changing the code in your service's delete method to be this:

```
return axios.delete(`http://localhost:8081/api/${idLowongan}`)
```